# Binary Search Tree Delete Node With One Child

Tags: binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree and when I try to do the case where you delete a node with a single child, you delete that node and move the child node in it's place. I have the code for it but it's giving me a bad pointer whenever I do it.

This is the segment of the code

```
else if((root->Left != NULL) != (root->Right != NULL)){ //Checks if it's a on child node
    if(root->Left != NULL){ //If it has a left child, attempts to move the left child to existing node
        delete root;
        root = root->Left;
    }
    else{ //If it is right child, attempts to move right child to existing node
        delete root;
        root = root->Right;
    }
}
```

The struct has values

```
DATA_TYPE Value;
TreeNode* Left;
TreeNode* Right;
```

I know I'm allocating it wrong from the debugger, so what's the correct way to move the node?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Don't know how I missed it but you're using `root` right after deleting it.

Edit2:
You need a temporary.

```
TreeNode* temp = root->Right;
delete root;
root = temp;
```

Comment: I was told that you actually had to delete it first, so I went along with it, but if you just use = to reassign then what happens to that node? Because it just stores that space forever and you have no way of deleting it now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java implementation for the method

```
public void removeHalfNodes () {

    if ( root == null ) return;
    if ( root.left == null && root.right == null ) return;
    if ( root.left == null && root.right != null ) root = root.right;
    else if ( root.left != null && root.right == null ) 
        root = root.left;

    removeHalfNodesRec ( root );
}

public void removeHalfNodesRec ( BinaryTreeNode node ) {

    if ( node.left != null ) {
        if ( node.left.left == null && node.left.right != null )
            node.left = node.left.right;
        else if ( node.left.right == null && node.left.left != null )
            node.left = node.left.left;

        removeHalfNodesRec ( node.left );
    }

    if ( node.right != null ) {
        if ( node.right.left == null && node.right.right != null )
            node.right = node.right.right;
        else if ( node.right.right == null && node.right.left != null )
            node.right = node.right.left;

        removeHalfNodesRec ( node.right );
    }
}
```